# Should I overwrite files in Laravel public storage or delete them first?

Tags: laravel, storage

I am working on an `update` function for a `cms` and want to know if it is safe to just overwrite files by using the same `path` in `put` or if this could lead to problems in the future. So instead of:

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete($path);
Storage::disk('public')->put($path, base64_decode($image));
```

I'd just do:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($path, base64_decode($image));
```

What do you think?

Comment: There is nothing to be said against deleting the path first?

Comment: Is it necessary is my question

Answer (score 0):

It is depends how you generate your filename. If you use the `$file->getClientOriginalName()` and `-extension()` it would be unsafe because you can overwritten an already existing file (if you push all files in a same directory). On the other hand if you previously remove the filename it could be that you remove a already filename, too. What i try to say: It depends on your file storage strategy.

There are at minimum three ways to solve the problem.

1. rename the file to unique name
2. create a subfolder
3. use an extern media lib to solve this problem. For example Spati Media Lib (https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction).